# Cannot force Debian to start in Framebuffer 640x480 resolution

Tags: debian, console, framebuffer

In order to port an embedded project from an ARM target to Linux/x86, I have to create a Debian VM (I'm using Virtualbox right now) which starts in framebuffer mode with 640x480 resolution.

I used the `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` command to make the VM start on framebuffer, but it seems it cannot go below 800x600 resolution.
All tutorials and guide I can find are related to starting the guest VM at high resolution modes, while I cannot find anything tackling with my issue.

I followed the suggestions found at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=83189

```
edit /etc/default/grub 
Uncomment: #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480 
Modify it to required resolution: GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768 
Add the following: GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep 
Save, exit, and run update-grub 
Edit "/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf" and add vboxvideo Reboot
```

Using `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and creating the `/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf` file, but with no results - it keeps starting at 800x600

Can anyone help on this? I am currently using Debian 9, can move to another version in case of incompatibilities.

EDIT: as requested, here is the output of #cat /proc/cmdline:

`BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-11-amd64 root=UUID=5bb1ded6-45a6-4d13-93d8-5f593e66e609 ro quiet`

Comment: can you post the output of /proc/cmdline   - this will tell us what parameters are passed to the kernel to see what, if any, video modes are set.

Comment: I updated the original post, thanks for any insight

Comment: In /etc/default/grub. set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX option to include "vga=ask" and the update grub.  At boot time this will prompt for which resolution to choose.  See if that fixes it and then change to the vga=ask option to be something more permanent.

Comment: I get a "legacy parameter ask no more supported", and then the system hangs when trying to load the ramdisk. It looks like grub2 no longer allows to pass that parameter to linux.

Comment: Ok, at a grub prompt (press c at the grub menu), type vbeinfo to get a list of the supported video modes and then see if 640x480 is there and set it directly in /etc/default/grub

Comment: It is supported, but I added "GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480" to my default/grub already.

Comment: I mean you find the code for 640x480 via the vbeinfo command and then set vga=<code> as a kernel parameter in /etc/default/grub

Comment: apparently, the "quiet" parameter was switching the console to 800x600 shortly after startup. Not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this can be of any help for other people, I was able to boot in VGA mode with the following change in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

instead of

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

This enables all the startup messages and, for some reason, also keeps the console in VGA resolution. I found this bit of relevant advice at https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-increase-tty-console-resolution-on-ubuntu-18-04-server

As far as I can see, the VGA resolution can be set with either

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

or

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=""
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=640x480
```

Comment: `nomodeset` kills lots of functionality of GPU's by disabling KMS. The `GFXMODE` stuff is good though

Comment: Not sure if there is any other way. I need to boot in VGA mode, without the "nomodeset" it starts in 800x600.

Answer (score 1):

In VirtualBox Manager File -> Preferences -> Display the Maximum Guest Screen Size parameter can be automatic/none/hint

With a size None or Hint with the desired size did it for me.

FYI : GRUB config :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE= the one you want (1024x768x32 in my case)
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX= keep or the one you want  (1024x768x32 in my case)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console (kept in comment)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

to boot in normal text mode, ‘keep’ to preserve the graphics mode set using gfxmode

[source](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#gfxpayload)

Comment: According to the details in his question, he's already done that.

Comment: the first part yes, but Marco veglio did not mention my 2. part.

Comment: ??? Read the suggestions that he followed.

Comment: Oh, where are my glasses.  My fault.

Comment: What drives me mad is that the VM actually *tries* to start in VGA resolution (the grub splash screen is in VGA, as well as the "loading ramdisk" message), but almost immediately it reverts to 800x600